# create dynamic interface for material table datasource

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a generic  component for viewing query results containing dynamic fields.

I use `mat-table` to view the data, but the pagination and the sort features don't work.

The function `setDataSource` is called from parent component.

I think this is happening because the datasource declaration doesn't implement the interface.

How can I set datasource with dynamic interface?

My Html:

```
<mat-table matTableExporter matSort #exporter="matTableExporter" [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of displayedColumns;let colIndex=index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{disCol}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[disCol]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 50]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'report', sheet: 'sheet 1', Props: {Author: 'Me'}})">Excel</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [];
dataSource: any = [];
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

public setDataSource(data,column) {
    this.displayedColumns = column;
    this.dataSource = data;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide minimal reproducible example, for example in fiddle - this will hugely speed up answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by generating a new datasource every time the data changes and then set the paginator and sorter.

**EDIT:** Add setter for paginator and sorter and change `static` attribute to false. Also add a check before setting the paginator and sorter in the `setDataSource` function.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator; // change static to false here
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) set matPaginator(value: MatPaginator) {
  if(this.dataSource && value) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = value;
  }
}

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort; // change static to false here
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) set matSort(value: MatSort) {
  if(this.dataSource && value) {
    this.dataSource.sort = value;
  }
}

public setDataSource(data,columns) {  // data -> array of elements; columns -> columns you wish to display
  this.displayedColumns = columns;        
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(data);  // replace any with your data type
  if(this.paginator) {   // add check here
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  if(this.sort) {  // add check here
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your table or your paginator wrapped in an `ngIf`?

Comment: yes, the table and the paginator both is inner ngIf, but the table works and the the paginator shown but not work

Comment: It works! Thank you. I'm sorry but I'm new and can't vote yet. With  G-d help I will vote later.

Answer (score 0):

In case the complete data is loaded into the client, you should use `MatTableDataSource`. This class is aimed to be used for filtering, sorting and pagination of a client-side data array.

When filtering, sorting and pagination are done server-side, the use of this class is not appropriate. In such cases, the relevant data may be kept in a simple array, hence no need to implement a specific interface. A good example is given at https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/.

Comment: The sorting and the pagination is in client side in my case.